# Cant get full height using meteor-admin-lte

Tags: javascript, meteor, adminlte

I am using meteor admin lte. My application renders on only half the screen.
[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLzAf.png) the screenshot of the problem.

I tried this [solution](https://github.com/meteor-factory/meteor-admin-lte/issues/17) but it didn't help. What can I do to remove this problem? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the relative position on for the following line.

> `<div class="wrapper" style="min-height: 100%;">  ---- </div>`

[image]

Comment: Removing the `position: relative` css rule worked. Thanks a lot1

Comment: I am unable to change AdminLTE.min.css. I guess it must be getting created off a .less file or maybe something else. How can I enforce this ?

Comment: You can either write custom CSS on div or create a new class.

Comment: Is there any possible side effect of this solution Pankaj Ji?

Answer (score 0):

I am not css guru but as far as I know if you wan't to get something to work with height: 100%; the parent element should have fixed height. It looks like one of your elements has wrong height as there is obviously more content which is overflowed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake on the github solution. In the first line it's written

```
Template.<layout>.created = function () {
```

It should be

```
Template.<layout>.onCreated = function () {
```

Give us more information and we could give you a better answers for your problem, but first try the above solution.

Comment: I have tried this solution and its not working. Please tell me what information you require. I am using meteor-admin-lte and trying to render the dashboard in it. The html can be taken from the original adminlte source code.